# How do I connect these two forms to get the input working in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am having trouble getting these two forms to just show the number input from my Virtualized Keyboard. Essentially what is going on here is that I have a numeric keypad passing in the numbers from the virtualized keyboard and a currency component to be able to have the currency format (thousand commas, and decimals). 
Here is the UI for better idea of what I'm trying to explain.

[image: Here is the UI for better idea of what I'm trying to explain.]

When I press the keypad it says this:

This is the error I get

[image: This is the error I get]

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  ImageBackground,
  Dimensions,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  SafeAreaView,
  TextInput,
  Keyboard
} from "react-native";

import { Block, Text, theme } from "galio-framework";
import VirtualKeyboard from 'react-native-virtual-keyboard';
import CurrencyInput from '../components/CurrencyInput';
import Button from '../components/Button'
import { HeaderHeight } from "../constants/utils";

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("screen");



const Give = () => {


  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const handleValueChange = useCallback(val => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log(val);
    setValue(val);
  }, []);




  return (

    <View style={style.container}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Block style={style.allContainer}>
          <Block style={style.numberContainer}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss()} accessible={false} >
              <CurrencyInput
                max={100000000}
                onValueChange={handleValueChange}
                style={style.inputNumber}
                value={value}
              />
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </Block>
          <VirtualKeyboard color='#000' pressMode='string' onPress={(val) => setValue(val)} />
          <Button style={style.button}><Text style={style.buttonText}>Ofrendar</Text></Button>
        </Block>

      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  )
}



const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? -HeaderHeight : 0,
    height: height,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    width: width
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    width: width,
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover",
  },
  animationContainer: {


  },
  animationImage: {
    height: 250,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    alignSelf: "center",

  },
  ofrenda: {
    fontSize: 55,
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 70
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "#FFF",
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    letterSpacing: 2
  },
  button: {
    height: 60,
    width: width - theme.SIZES.BASE * 6,
    marginBottom: 30,
    marginTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: "#00a8ff",
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: "#00a8ff",
    shadowColor: "transparent"




  },
  bottomButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 30
  },
  numberContainer: {


  },
  inputNumber: {
    fontSize: 50,
    fontWeight: "bold"

  },
  allContainer: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: height,
    width: width,
    alignSelf: "center"


  }




});

export default Give;
```

Comment: What does `CurrencyInput` send to `handleValueChange`? What is the type of `val`?

Comment: Hello! What it should pass is the values in the text input as a formatted currency format. Values that are pressed on the virtual keyboard are not passing to the text input in currencyInput component as they should.